# Shared memory segment shared between a 32 and 64 bit processes

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

Is it possible to create a shared memory segment that can be accessed by both 32 and 64 bit processes. The flag'TPF_IPC64' to support 64 bit addressing is as below

```
shmget(key,100,IPC_CREAT|TPF_IPC64);
```

Will this be accessible from a 32 bit Linux process?

Edit: It seems like the flag 'TPF_IPC64' is not supported in a normal Linux OS call to shmget. I think it is some proprietary to IBM ( my bad). I took it from this link

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtpc2%2Fcpp_shmget.html

Answer (score 4):

man shmget(2)

> If IPC_CREAT is set in shmflg the shared memory segment created can
>   only be shared by processes of the same executable type. That is, an
>   application compiled as a 32-bit process will be able to share the
>   same memory segment with other 32-bit processes, and an application
>   compiled as a 64-bit process will be able to share the same memory
>   segment with other 64-bit processes. If a 64-bit bit process want to
>   create a shared memory segment which can also be shared with 32-bit
>   processes, the 64-bit process must specify IPC_SHARE32 in addition to
>   IPC_CREAT in shmflg . The 32-bit process does not need to specify
>   IPC_SHARE32 .On Itanium(R)-based platforms, if the Adaptive Address
>   Space feature is being used, then additional rules may apply. See the
>   section below on Adaptive Address Space.

Comment: I do not see this in the my shmget man page. Also IPC_SHARE32 is not recognized. I could find this in some HP documentation. Could you give me more details on how to use it?

Comment: I cannot see IPC_SHARE32 in the link you provided

Comment: It also looks like this is supported only in HP-Ux which is a proprietary implementation of unix by HP

Answer (score 0):

From [IBM's](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtpc2%2Fcpp_shmget.html) document

`TPF_IPC64
    Specifies that 64-bit addressing is supported. If you specify this flag, 64-bit system heap is used to satisfy the request if there is enough heap available. If there is no 64-bit system heap space available, 31-bit system heap will be used. Specify this flag only if all the users of this shared memory area can support 64-bit addresses.`

The last sentence has mentioned that all the process has to support 64-bit address. So process with 32-bit address cannot access it.

However, I don't what is the behavior if you tried to access it with 32-bit process.